# Not Calling java Action via Ajax in jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

vehicleinfo.js

```
function updateWCPolicyPresentValue(changedValue){
    var url = $.url($(this).prop('href'));
    var id = url.param('id');
    alert(id);
    if(confirm("Change will apply to all vehicles for this policy. Is it okey?")){
        $.ajax({
        url: '<s:url action="wcPolicyPresentVehicleInformationAction" namespace="/" />?   changedValue='+changedValue+'&keepUrlRegistry=true',
            cache : false,
            success : alert(changedValue)
        });
    }else{
        $.unblockScreen();
    }

    return false;

}
```

Struts-cpp.xml

```
<action name="*VehicleInformationAction" method="{1}"    class="com.sbi.fremont.bindexpress.cpp.web.action.VehicleInformationAction">
        <result name="input" type="tiles">vehicleInformationPageCpp</result>
        <result name="load" type="redirectAction">inputVehicleInformationAction?id=${selectedId}&amp;loadType=${loadType}&amp;fleetMessage=${fleetMessage}</result>
</action>
```

1. In here, I am trying to call vehicleInformationAction java class via ajax request but it is not calling. I want to check that is there any mistake in ajax format?

Comment: you define a url variable but I don't see you using it in the ajax call.  Try doing a console.log on what you are using for the url and try navigating to that url.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<result name="load" type="redirectAction">
    inputVehicleInformationAction?id=${selectedId}&amp;loadType=${loadType}&amp;fleetMessage=${fleetMessage}
</result>
```

to

```
<result name="load" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">inputVehicleInformationAction</param>
    <param name="id">${selectedId}</param>
    <param name="loadType">${loadType}</param>
    <param name="fleetMessage">${fleetMessage}</param>
</result>
```